Set material as Image texture
I'm trying to make a pumpkin head creature.
I found a object and material file I like, and assigned the material to the desired faces.
However it does not have a native Texture Image so when I go to import it to character creator 4 the intended texture areas come up blank.
How do I set the Material as a Texture Image?
as an example I get this

but then it turns into this upon export


This looks like a job for baking to new images for the diffuse, normal, and roughness at least. You will need to make sure you have an UV unwrap in place and then use a new unconnected image node selected and active to bake to. Make sure to turn off denoise before baking otherwise you may have problems.

You have to find the textures which are  assigned to the material, if they are procedural - meaning they are made from the labor of nodes - then you have to do what Craig wrote. Now if that doesn't work it's likely an exportation/importation problem, perhaps CC4 has a particular way of handling things which are not the scope of this forum.

@Craiq and Yerus Thank you Both hat helps.
